# Desktop background appears black when using XFCE

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

I've installed Xfce4 on my laptop which runs Linux Mint 17 with Cinamon default desktop. Everything works OK and I customized my lightweight Xfce, like change menu location and desktop background that it is similar to my Cinamon desktop and used it for a while.

Suddenly after last restart my desktop background becomes black and there is no option for desktop background change when I right click on desktop. I should mention that

```
xfdesktop &
```

didn't help, which tells it's already running. Some icons like **Computer**, **Home** and **Oracle VM** that was already there is showing, but my **Trash** or other icons did not. I've tried everywhere in

```
xfce4-settings-manager
```

but could not get my desktop background back

running 
    xfdesktop

cause this message:

```
** (xfdesktop:3068): WARNING **: xfdesktop: another desktop manager is running.
```

running

```
killall xfdesktop
```

results

```
xfdesktop: no process found
```

It seems to me another process takes place of xfdesktop
I don't know how can I find and replace it

Comment: Does anything different happen if you kill the running `xfdesktop` process before attempting to run it again? You can do this with `killall xfdesktop` (then run that again a few seconds later, and if you don't get `xfdesktop: no process found`, forcibly kill it with `killall -KILL xfdesktop`). After killing `xfdesktop`, try running it again, this time *without* `&`. The `&` isn't causing the problem, but by running it in the foreground you're more likely to see output in the terminal that might reveal the nature of the problem. (You can edit your question with detailed results.)

Comment: Have you tried to run `xfdesktop-settings` and change the background there?

Comment: running xfdesktop cause this message: ** (xfdesktop:3068): WARNING **: xfdesktop: another desktop manager is running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could get my desktop back with the following steps:

1.Run:

```
xfce4-settings-manager
```

2.Select **Session and Startup**

3.Select **Application Autostart** tab

4.click **Add**

5.On the window appeared enter name, description and

```
xfdesktop --replace
```

as command

6.Logout and Login again

Comment: I have this issue now with Linux Mint 18 MATE and installed XFCE settings manager to follow your instructions, but Session and Startup is not a thing on it now.

Comment: I'll just mention that I just had this problem (XFCE on Slackware), and just running xfdesktop by itself did the trick.